# Как узнать процент покрытия Jest и React testing library?

Tags: reactjs, юнит-тесты, react-native, react-hook, jest

Изучаю технологию Jest, написала тестовый код и покрыла его тестами. С помощью команды хочу узнать общий процент покрытия `jest --coverage` получаю ошибку при запросе. Можно ли, как то узнать какой процент покрытия?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Как вы установили проект? Это create-react-app?

Comment: да create-react-app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В `package.json` добавляете этот код. Если есть, то меняйте.

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "react-scripts test --coverage",
     //..
},
```

И вызываете уже через `npm t`. Этот код будет генерировать отдельную папку `coverage` на котором будет несколько файлов, включая `index.html`.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

B этом файле будет полный отчет, какой файл сколько покрыт, какие линии остались не покрытыми.

Эти данные также будут отображаться на терминале.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Также можно добавить конфигурацию jest-а в файл `package.json`, чтобы указать в каких файлах не считать тесты, а в каких наоборот, считать.

В конфигурации который я указал jest будет смотреть все `.tsx` файлы в папке `src` за исключением папки `node_modules`.

```
"jest": {
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
        "src/**/*.tsx",
        "!**/node_modules/**",
    ]
}
```

Есть еще очень много интересных настроек [**jest-a**](https://jestjs.io/ru/docs/configuration#collectcoveragefrom-array)